# How to rollback all the insert and update that are done in different tables from different function calls that are called through the single api

Tags: mysql, transactions, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions

I am calling an API to save the production data, I need to save various details like batch no, machine no, and process in different database

```java
Class ProductionImpl{

    public Long saveProduction(AddProduct addproduct){
    
        BatchData batchdata = batchDao.save(addproduct);
        \\
        ProductionPlane pp = productionPlanDao.save(addproduct,batchdata);
        MachineData machineData = new MachineData();
        machineData.setProductionId = pp.getId;
        \\
        saveMachine(machineData);
        return pp.getId;
    }
    \\
}


Class MachineImpl{

    public void saveMachine(machineData){
    
        ProductionPlane p_plan = productionPlanDao.findBy(machineDaata.getProductionId);
        \\
        MachineDao.save(machineData);
    }
    \\
}
```

if the error occurs in saveMachine I want to rollback the changes in saveProduction also.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Saga pattern](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-saga-pattern-in-microservices-9eaadde79748). Here is how I would do it using the [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source framework:

```java
  public Long saveProduction(AddProduct addproduct){
    // Configure SAGA to run compensation activities in parallel
    Saga.Options sagaOptions = new Saga.Options.Builder().build();
    Saga saga = new Saga(sagaOptions);
    try {

        BatchData batchdata = batchActivity.save(addproduct);
        saga.addCompensation(batchActivity::undoSave, batchdata);

        ProductionPlane pp = productionPlanActivity.save(addproduct,batchdata);
        saga.addCompensation(productionPlanActivity::undoSave, pp);

        MachineData machineData = new MachineData();
        machineData.setProductionId = pp.getId;
        macnhineActivity.saveMachine(machineData);
        return pp.getId;
    } catch (ActivityFailure e) {
      saga.compensate();
      throw e;
    }
  }
```